# Why we can see cone of white light (not blue) from torch in night but not in day light?

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life, scattering, vision

Why we don't see blue colour when we look forward in a open ground, sunrays are there and gases are there. Then why it is not appearing blue like sky but white?

Also when I turn on a torch in day light its path is not visible when looking from side. But in night if we turn on torch, we can see a cone like structure while looking from side, why don't we see a bluish cone as white light scatter blue the most in atmosphere, instead we see white light! Why?

Similarly, How red Cone of light house is visible from side in night but not much in day time?

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/243683/44126).

Comment: Very nice answer, so sir wgen we on the torch as you said below planetary boundry we have many large scatterers, so white light from torch light cone is much more scattered and due to torch intensity, blue light scatter but in comparison of much more white scattering we dont see bluish glow in cone but only white glow!! Right?

Comment: It's more that daylight is bright, and the distance over which the flashlight beam is visible is too short to reveal that air is blue. I'm sure you've had the experience of looking at a vehicle's headlights in the daytime and not being quite sure whether they're on or not. Daylight is really bright; backscatter from aerosol is much less so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At night, if you had sensitive enough equipment, you could see the blue component of the white light from the torch.

I would guess that the light coming out of a torch simply does not have an intensity high enough (and shining over a large enough area), so that the blue component of the light is clearly visible. In other words, you would need a significantly large number of light scattering events over a large area so that you would see significant amounts of blue light visible to the naked eye.

When you see a cone light structure coming from the torch, it is usually because of dust particles in the atmosphere reflecting the light.

When a torch is on during the day, you also need to remember that there is also plenty of light from the sun, whose brightness will outshine the light coming from the torch. This is similar to why you cannot see stars during the daytime.

Comment: So u mean white cone we see is due to scattering of white light by large particles while blue scattered by air is very less to be noticed?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you aren't looking closely enough. It does appear blue.

2nd: Water is also colored blue, slightly, but a small cup of water looks perfectly clear. In fact air has more or less the same properties as water would if it was 1000x less dense.

3rd: When you shine a torch on a surface it's visible, but when you shine it on a surface that's already lit more brightly it isn't. Likewise with the scatter from a cone of light.

Comment: So why we see a white cone of torch in night when we look from side, while blue colour is scattered by atmosphere. Ok if blue colour scatter is very less due to intensity but how white colour is visible than, air molecules doesnt scatter white light equally.