# How light house actually help and does white light from light house appear a bluish cone in air due to scattering or simply appears white?

Tags: visible-light, scattering

How 'light house'  actually work ?

How does light from light house appear to a ship far away and close away ? As colour can change due to scattering distance so does all ships either far or close see only one colour from light house I.e white?

Comment: Who says that red light is used in light houses??

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/670502/why-we-can-see-cone-of-white-light-not-blue-from-torch-in-night-but-not-in-day) and  [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243565/why-do-beams-of-light-from-torches-or-other-directed-sources-not-extend-to-inf).

Comment: Can anyone answer it?            https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/670687/313211

Comment: @josephh FYI This user and the OP in your first link are one and the same.

Comment: @BobD Thanks.--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Light houses worked by warning sailors of rocks/land by having a visible light there.

Air scatters light mainly in the blue part of the spectrum, so from far away the light might appear redder than the original source - although it didn't really matter to the sailors what frequency of light was visible.

Early lighthouses used a fire for the light source, presumably with a red/orange light - for example Egypt's Pharos of Alexandria, built around 280 BC.

Later lighthouses had a light source that rotated and focused the light into a narrow beam, so that it could be seen from further away.

You might want to look into [Fresnel lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_lens)

[image]

Comment: +1 for excellent answer. Also worth noting that the rotating lens means (a) ships see a flashing light which makes the light more noticeable and (b) ships can use the frequency and pattern of flashes to identify individual lighthouses.

Comment: @ gandalf61 , true, good points